# Does "technie" mean "technical guy"?

Tags: terminology, slang

I’ve remembered that I read somewhere the word *technie* means *technical guy*. However, I couldn’t find that definition “on the internet”.

Seems like *technie* is “slang”.  Does *technie* really mean *technical guy*?

Comment: You probably mean  ***techie***: *a technical expert, student, or enthusiast, especially in the field of electronics.* http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/techie

Comment: Usually we say "*techie*", no `n`.  And it does mean "technical guy", but there are several possible connotations.

Comment: "Techie" covers a broad range.  It may simply mean the next-door neighbor's 14-year-old kid who helps untangle your computer for you, or it may mean someone with a PhD in some technological field.  Usually it implies someone with practical vs purely theoretical abilities.

Comment: (Of course, one could also take "Tekkie" to mean a non-rhotic "Trekkie". ;) )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***[Techie](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/techie) (or tekkie)*** is the term you are looking for. It is a slang term from the early 80's generally used to to refer to a technical expert or someone who is highly interested or proficient in a technical field, especially electronics.

> - a technical expert, student, or enthusiast, especially in the field of electronics.
> - a technician, as for a stage crew.
>
>   - 1980-1985; tech(nical) + -ie

(Random House Dictionary)

[Techie](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=techie%20&searchmode=none):

> - one well-versed in the latest technology, by 1984.

(Etymonline)

[Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=techie%20&year_start=1970&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctechie%3B%2Cc0): *techie*.

Comment: Yeah, but try Ngram on technie, you'll be surprised. (Hint: OCR has its limitations).

Comment: @WhatRoughBeast - https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=techie%2Ctechnie&year_start=1970&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctechie%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Ctechnie%3B%2Cc0. What is surprising?

Comment: Look at technie alone. https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=technie&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Ctechnie%3B%2Cc0 Notice the peak. If you don't realize the OCR problem, it suggests a remarkable reduction in usage of a word which was (apparently) quite common.

Comment: Checking into texts, it appears the term is not used to mean 'tech expert' though!

Comment: @Josh61, in the Ngram, why do more people use the word "technie" than "techie" before 1980. But, more and more people  use "technie" from 1969 onward

Comment: @user105551 - the term 'technie' is apparently used with the meaning of 'technique' as in : "The differences in statistics being due to the position of the tumor, the extent of the operation required, the technie employed, the skill of the operator, and whether the case came to operation early...". https://www.google.it/search?q=%22technie%22&tbs=bks:1,cdr:1,cd_min:1921,cd_max:1956&lr=lang_en&gws_rd=cr,ssl&ei=oSevVcffCMitsgGU2bfoDw

Answer (score 0):

It is actually spelled [Techie](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/techie) which is probably why you could not find it but otherwise, you're basically right. It usually refers to somebody who is skilled with advanced technology or complex technological devices, especially but not limited to the electronic variety.

The members of the I.T. department; many kinds of repairmen like mechanics; engineers; inventors; amateur [techno-geeks](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/techno-geek); a band's stage crew, including the pyrotechnics team and sometimes chemists are a few examples of people that may be considered techies.

I believe more natural fields mitigate against being considered a techie. You probably would not refer to plumbers, carpenters and builders as techies, since these are older skilled trades. You usually would not refer to a physician as a techie either, since the focus of the art is biological, although physicians might refer to certain medical technicians as techies amongst themselves.

The word is sometimes used to indicate a sort of distanced relationship or social divide between techies and [the uninitiated](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/uninitiated) or [normies](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/normie). The groups will often discuss how they "can't get (understand)" one another. I think the article [Dilbert Makes His Point: How Techies Speak with Positive Impact to Non-techies](http://bio2devicegroup.org/content/dilbert-makes-his-point-how-techies-speak-positive-impact-non-techies-yvonne-t-ryan-08242010) by Yvonne T. Ryan for the Bio2Device Group and [Omics, Big Data & What the Techies Don’t Get](http://www.drmichaeljoyner.com/omics-big-data-what-the-techies-dont-get/) by Michael J. Joyner, M.D. on the Human Limits blog, demonstrate this point decently enough, even just by the titles of the articles alone.

Sometimes somebody might say "You're a techie, right?" as a way of indicating they want assistance from somebody with expertise they suspect you possess. Others somebody might be asked to go and "get the techies" indicating that there should be some technicians on standby elsewhere who need to be retrieved in order to help with a particular circumstance, especially if its difficult or urgent.

---

> **Citations:**
>
> Random House Kernerman Webster’s College Dictionary. S.v. "techie." Retrieved from The Free Dictionary by Farlex
>
> Techno-Geek (somebody whose primary interest is electronics, esp. related to computers): The Longman Dictionary of Conteporary English
>
> [Normie](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/normie) (normal person, [rare, context sensitive and often mildly derogatory]): Wiktionary
>
> Collins English Dictionary – Complete and Unabridged. S.v. "uninitiated." Retrieved July 21 2015 from http://www.thefreedictionary.com/uninitiated